# Database project publish issue when build action set to none

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

When i choose `build action to none` in visual-studio database project, i am not able to publish script to database and if i set it to `Build` then its throw error like

```
this statement is not recognized in this context database project
```

please let me know if there any way to resolved this issue.

Comment: Too little info. on which statement is it failing?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev when we user `insert` and `set` in query.

Comment: I think that the real code example is the best answer for my question. Currently it is impossible to answer your question as it could be literally everything